# Vector subscript out of range error in heapify function

Tags: vector, heapsort

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

void heapsort(vector<int> &input,int count){

}

int max_v(int tree[]){
    int result;

    result=tree[0];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(tree[i]>result){
            result=tree[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

bool judge(vector<int> &input,int count){
    int j=0;
    int start;
    double parent=0;
    double lchild;
    double rchild;
    int tree[3];
    int max;
    double i;

    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        parent=floor((i-1)/2);
        lchild=2*i+1;
        rchild=2*i+2;
        if(lchild>count-1){i++;}
        if(rchild>count-1){i++;}
        tree[0]=input[parent];
        tree[1]=input[lchild];
        tree[2]=input[rchild];
        max=max_v(tree);
        if(input[parent]!=max){j++;}
    }
    if(j==0){return true;}

    return false;
}

void heapify(vector<int> &input,int count){
   double parent=0;
   double lchild;
   double rchild;
   int tree[3];
   int max;
   double i=0;

   while(judge(input,count)==false){
       for(i=0;i<count;i++){
            parent=floor((i-1)/2);
            lchild=2*i+1;
            rchild=2*i+2;
            if(lchild>count-1){i++;}
            if(rchild>count-1){i++;}
            tree[0]=input[parent];
            tree[1]=input[lchild];
            tree[2]=input[rchild];
            max=max_v(tree);
            if(input[lchild]==max){swap(input[parent],input[lchild]);}
            if(input[rchild]==max){swap(input[parent],input[rchild]);}
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int count;
    int tmp;
    cin>>count;
    vector<int> input;

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        cin>>tmp;
        input.push_back(tmp);
    }
    cout<<endl;
    heapify(input,count);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        cout<<input[i]<<" ";
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

hi,as topic stated,i found error in my heapify function which suppose to ensure each parent node has the max value in its corresponding binary tree.The error is about vector subscript out of range but i cannot find out  which vector index is out of the range .Please help and thanks to everyone helping.

Comment: oh gee, you have to fix the indent first.

Comment: Do not indent with tabs.  Especially do not indent with a mixture of tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The termination condition of the `for` loop in your `heapify()` function is incorrect.  The loop will proceed through indices corresponding to the leaf nodes of your proto-heap, and try to extract *their* children as `index[lchild]` and `index[rchild]`.  Or actually just the former, because that's where your subscript violation occurs.

Also, why in the world are you using `double`s for your counters and indices?  You should be using an integral type.  `int` would be the default choice.  The result will be clearer and slightly faster, and you will be able to avoid the `floor()` function altogether.